# Is there any Enterprise Orchestration tool apart from OpenShift for Bare metal environment?

Tags: containers, enterprise, orchestration, bare-metal-server

I am trying to find an Enterprise Orchestration tool for managing container over my single Bare Metal server.

Open Shift is not fine for my environment. It would be great if anyone can suggest me other enterprise tools for the same.

Answer (score 0):

During my research, I found there are very few enterprises tools. The details are as below:

> Charmed Ubuntu https://ubuntu.com/kubernetes/features
>   Kontena Pharos https://www.kontena.io/pharos
>   SuSE caas https://www.suse.com/products/caas-platform

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise orchestration tools you can setup on bare metal.

- Kubernetes - K8s
- Mesosphere - https://mesosphere.com/product
- Rancher - https://rancher.com/
- Docker swarm Enterprise edition - https://www.docker.com/blog/swarm-orchestration-in-docker-enterprise-edition/